# UML: Object Diagram

Tags: c, uml

I am beginner in UML.
The following is  a  UML object-model diagram that shows a single object called Timer, which has attributes minutes and seconds of type integer, as well as public operations tick() and reset().

[image]

The correspondig C Structure is:

```
struct Timer_t {
   int mins;    /*## attribute mins */
   int secs;    /*## attribute secs */
};

/* Operations */
/*## operation reset() */
void Timer_reset();
/*## operation tick() */
void Timer_tick();
```

With respect to this diagram I would like to understand the physical interpretation of the following:

1- `1` at the top left (Is it no. of instances that will be instantiated during the lifetime of the application?)

2-  `<<Singleton>>`  (If it is stereotype to highlight that the object is an instance of a singleton class, then why do we also mention 1 at the top left?)

source :  [UML for C Programmers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/uml-for-c-programmers/184401948)

Answer (score 2):

First, the above is not an object(/instance) but a class. An object does not show attributes/methods in compartments and the name would be underlined.

Second, the `<<Singleton>>` stereotype is placed wrongly. It needs to appear under the name of the class.

Third, the `1` top left signaling multiplicity needs to be enclosed in brackets like `{1}`. Not sure about the position, I just know right below the class name.

Now regarding your question. The multiplicity tells that there must be only one instance of this class in a system. The stereotype `<<Singleton>>` doesn't tell anything else (it's a tautology). However, the name Singleton is well known and you can find implementation patterns for any language via Google - which will fail for the key word `1`;-)

Comment: from this source: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/uml-for-c-programmers/184401948   as you can see they call it: Figure 1: Timer object.

Comment: This is a class diagram for a single object model. But yes, it is a class diagram. All that @thomaskilian wrote is accurate and true. I would recommend you start with reading some about UML itself before you go with a link between UML and C.

Comment: Just that one claims to have a doctor's degree does not make all his saying be correct ;-) Generally, using OO in non-OO languages is tricky. Prof. Floyd where I once had a class used COBOL to teach (sort of) OO because  there it's extremely difficult to do the split between both worlds.